# Mercurial .hgignore: Some questions on how to ignore a single file

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

There's a particular file in my repository, libraries/database.php, that I need ignored. However, I can't get the syntax to recognize the file - I've tried `**/libraries/**/database.php` and `libraries/database.php` in glob, and `^.libraries/database.php` in regex, but neither of them work. What should I do?

Comment: Weird. Just did the following (on windows):

C:\kev\DPX2>touch a DPX\a

C:\kev\DPX2>hg stat
? DPX\a
? a

C:\kev\DPX2>echo DPX/a >> .hgignore

C:\kev\DPX2>hg stat
M .hgignore
? a

Works fine for me. Are you giving the full path relative to the repository directory?

Oops, sorry about formatting. New lines not honoured - hope its clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
syntax: re
^libraries/database\.php$
```

That will work.

But, frankly, I've always found the .hgignore syntax to be a little obscure myself.  I don't really understand what glob will and won't match.

Comment: As far as I know glob will just try to match the whole line given within the relative (to the repository's root) path. As an example "glob:makefile" will exclude everything that has "makefile" in its path and/or name

Comment: @David - The actual names of the two supported syntaxes are `relre` and `relglob`.  But `re` and `regexp` are aliases for `relre`, and `glob` is an alias for `relglob`.  This is explicitly so in `ignore.py`.  This has been the case since this syntax for `.hgignore` files was introduced in changeset fc3b41570082.

Comment: thank you, I will try to be less cocky next time :-) I was stating from the documentation.

Comment: @Dave - *grin*  Well, I noticed the documentation said that, and I knew that `syntax: re` worked, and had worked for me forever.  So I did some code spelunking to figure out if it simply worked by accident or if it was supposed to work.  It turns out (not too surprisingly) that the documentation is incomplete.

Answer (score 6):

After hours of following all the suggestions here and others found on the web, I found out that I was always doing it right in .hgignore, but .hgignore will not ignore files that are currently being tracked by mercurial.

You must do

```
hg forget mydir/myfile.ext
```

Or adding the file to .hgignore doesn't take affect.

```
syntax: glob
mydir/myfile.ext
```

Then the above will work.

Answer (score 1):

From the mercurial [QuickStart guide](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QuickStart#Setting_up_a_new_Mercurial_project):

"Mercurial will look for a file named .hgignore in the root of your repository which contains a set of glob patterns and regular expressions to ignore in file paths"

is your .hgignore at the right place ?

So

```
syntax: glob
libraries/database.php
```

should work.